# Performance impact of RDD API vs UDFs mixed with DataFrame API

Tags: scala, performance, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

(Scala-specific question.)

While Spark docs encourage the use of DataFrame API where possible, if DataFrame API is insufficient, the choice is usually between falling back to RDD API or using UDFs. Is there inherent performance difference between these two alternatives?

RDD and UDF are similar in that neither of them can benefit from Catalyst and Tungsten optimizations. Is there any other overhead, and if there is, does it differ between the two approaches?

To give a specific example, let's say I have a DataFrame that contains a column of text data with custom formatting (not amenable to regexp matching). I need to parse that column and add a new vector column that contains the resulting tokens.

Answer (score 17):

> neither of them can benefit from Catalyst and Tungsten optimizations

This is not exactly true. While UDFs don't benefit from Tungsten optimization (arguably simple SQL transformation don't get huge boost there either) you still may benefit from execution plan optimizations provided by Catalyst. Let's illustrate that with a simple example (Note: Spark 2.0 and Scala. Don't extrapolate this to earlier versions, especially with PySpark):

```
val f = udf((x: String) => x == "a")
val g = udf((x: Int) => x + 1)

val df = Seq(("a", 1), ("b", 2)).toDF

df
  .groupBy($"_1")
  .agg(sum($"_2").as("_2"))
  .where(f($"_1"))
  .withColumn("_2", g($"_2"))
  .select($"_1")
  .explain

// == Physical Plan ==
// *HashAggregate(keys=[_1#2], functions=[])
// +- Exchange hashpartitioning(_1#2, 200)
//    +- *HashAggregate(keys=[_1#2], functions=[])
//       +- *Project [_1#2]
//          +- *Filter UDF(_1#2)
//             +- LocalTableScan [_1#2, _2#3]
```

Execution plan shows us a couple of things:

- [Selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_%28relational_algebra%29) has been pushed down before aggregation.
- [Projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_%28relational_algebra%29) has been pushed down before aggregation and effectively removed second UDF call.

Depending on the data and pipeline this can provide a substantial performance boost almost for free.

That being said both RDDs and UDFs require migrations between safe and unsafe with the latter one being significantly less flexible. Still, if the only thing you need is a simple `map`-like behavior without initializing expensive objects (like database connections) then UDF is the way to go.

In slightly more complex scenarios you can easily drop down to generic `Dataset` and reserve `RDDs` for cases when you really require an access to some low level features like custom partitioning.

Comment: the optimization shown in the physical plan here is more of a catalyst optimization on the whole series of operations performed on the DF. But f($"_1") and g($"_2") won't be optimized by the spark in any way, all spark knows is, if I call the function it returns me a value. Assuming our function on the column is fairly optimized, the SQL query can be efficient. Is my understanding correct? But for spark this function is a black-box

Answer (score 1):

(Note: I don't have measured backing for this)

To me, shuffle and (de)serialization are the main costs. But after these, having clean code is most important. With that in mind:

The main drawback of using RDD operations is that a (de)serialization of/into full jvm objects is required. While using udf might only (de)serialize the required columns. Note that this is when processing column oriented data such as parquet, for other data format I don't know, but would expect that in many cases both have similar perf.

So, if your algorithm are mostly filtering and shuffling op, and/or can be simply expressed with dataframe op and local udf, you should use those. However, if your algorithms requires complex processing over many columns, it is probably better to pay deserialization up-front, and execute clean and efficient scala code on jvm objects.

So, in my personal experience where I implement complex mathematical algorithms, I typically split the code in two steps:

1. pure dataframe op to do as much of filtering, join and groupBy op. In rare cases I can use udf when a specific local op is required that cannot be expressed using dataframe method (and if it only need very few columns)
2. then convert to rdd and use (flat)map op for the math and or complex lookup parts