# Difference between a map and udf

Tags: scala, apache-spark, udf

When I work with DataFrames in Spark, I have to sometimes edit only the values of a particular column in that DataFrame. For eg. if I have a `count` field in my dataframe, and If I would like to add `1` to every value of `count`, then I could either write a custom udf to get the job done using the `withColumn` feature of DataFrames, or I could do a `map` on the DataFrame and then extract another DataFrame from the resultant RDD.

What I would like to know is how a udf actually works under the hood. Give me a comparison in using a map/udf in this case. What's the performance difference?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38860808/1560062

Answer (score 4):

Simply, `map` is more flexible than `udf`. With `map`, there is no restriction on the number of columns you can manipulate within a row. Say you want to derive the value for 5 columns of the data and delete 3 columns. You would need to do `withColumn`/`udf` 5 times, then a `select`. With 1 `map` function, you could do all of this.

Comment: If you're only processing one column, is it more efficient to use `withColumn`/`udf` than `map`?

Comment: In general, creating a dataframe from a RDD is going to have some overhead so `withColumn`/`udf` should be more efficient. For more details, zero323's response here might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/q/38860808/1560062